# Is there any way I can programmatically enable Google Chrome's native page translation feature?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I have my web page in english. Google Chrome has a feature to translate this page to a specified language by right clicking on the page and selecting "Translate to ".

I found that the translation is of good quality. So how can I enable this feature programmatically via JavaScript or html? Is there any browser (or chrome specific api) for this?

[image]

Comment: The [HTML `lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) is generally what browser's use to determine if translation should be offered. The browser compares its native language against what the `lang` attribute says and if they are different, the translation option becomes available.